# How to access prestashop functions in wordpress

Tags: module, prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.4.3 version. And I want to get user data in wordpress. I have tried below code with no luck. Giving me this Fatal error:

> Class 'FrontController' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/domin.com/prestashop/init.php on line 28.

Here is my script:

```
$psabspath = '';
$psabspath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/domin.com/prestashop/';

if ( $psabspath != '' && file_exists( $psabspath . 'config/config.inc.php' )
                                              && ( file_exists( $psabspath . 'classes/FrontController.php' ) ||
                                                   file_exists( $psabspath . 'classes/controller/FrontController.php' ) ) ) {
    require_once( $psabspath . 'init.php' );
    require_once( $psabspath . 'config/config.inc.php' );

    class PrestaShopIntegration_FrontController extends FrontController {
        public function __destruct()
        {
            if (Context::getContext()->cookie)
                Context::getContext()->cookie->write();
        }

        public function init() {
            $this->page_name = 'wordpress';
            parent::init();

            if ( isset( $this->context) ) {
                if ( version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.5.4', '>=') )
                    $this->setMedia();
                if ( $this->checkAccess() ) {
                    $this->postProcess();
                    $this->initHeader();
                    if ( $this->viewAccess() )
                        $this->initContent();
                    else
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Access denied.');
                    $this->initFooter();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first include `config.php` file and then you will be able to include `init.php`.

```php
$psabspath = '';
$psabspath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myskinrecipes.com/shop/';

if ( $psabspath != '' && file_exists( $psabspath . 'config/config.inc.php' )
                                              && ( file_exists( $psabspath . 'classes/FrontController.php' ) ||
                                                   file_exists( $psabspath . 'classes/controller/FrontController.php' ) ) ) {
    require_once( $psabspath . 'config/config.inc.php' );
    require_once( $psabspath . 'init.php' );

    class PrestaShopIntegration_FrontController extends FrontController {
        public function __destruct()
        {
            if (Context::getContext()->cookie)
                Context::getContext()->cookie->write();
        }

        public function init() {
            $this->page_name = 'wordpress';
            parent::init();

            if ( isset( $this->context) ) {
                if ( version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.5.4', '>=') )
                    $this->setMedia();
                if ( $this->checkAccess() ) {
                    $this->postProcess();
                    $this->initHeader();
                    if ( $this->viewAccess() )
                        $this->initContent();
                    else
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Access denied.');
                    $this->initFooter();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`config.php` will load Prestashop configuration files and load the entire Framework.

`init.php` is only there to load the controller.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Configuration' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/domin.com/prestashop/config/config.inc.php on line 105.

Comment: And line 105 have  this code Configuration::loadConfiguration();

Comment: Ok, I will dowload your specific Prestashop version, test it and come back to you asap.

Comment: I've tested it and it's working with a fresh installation. `config/config.inc.php` first load `config/autoload.php`. This file will load every Prestashop classes including `classes/Configuration.php`. Did you made any changes in `autoload.php`? If your shop is working, this script should be working too...

Comment: Also did you try putting your shop in development mode changing the first line `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` in `defines.inc.php` to `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`? Maybe some more errors will show on screen. You can also check for errors in your apache log files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115961/discussion-between-irfan-khan-and-florian-lemaitre).

Comment: I have tried many and many time. but i can't reached to error. but anyhow Really thank you so much :)

Comment: But please just clear me one think. i have create mycontoroller.php within shop. its return a just cookie array. This code which i include `include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/shop/config/config.inc.php');
$shopLoginDetail = ControllerFactory::getController('CheckController')->run();`  If I include within functions.php give me same the above error. if i include within wp-confiq.php then working